# Pseudofunctors of 2-variables and Gray tensor product of bicategories

Tags: higher-category-theory, 2-categories

Let $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B}, \mathcal{C}$ be bicategories. We say a 'pseudofunctors of 2-variables' consists of two families of pseufunctors

1. Fix $A\in obj\mathcal{A}$, we have a pseudofunctor $f(A,-): \mathcal{B}\to \mathcal{C}$.
2. Fix $B\in obj\mathcal{B}$, we have a psudofuncotr $f(-,B): \mathcal{A}\to \mathcal{C}$.
3. $f(A,-)(B)=f(-,B)(A):=f(A,B)$ for all $A\in obj\mathcal{A}, B\in\mathcal{B}$.
4. for all $\alpha: A\to A',\beta:B\to B'$, an invertible 2-cell $f(\alpha,\beta)$ between
   $$
   f(A,B)\xrightarrow{f(A, \beta)}f(A,B')\xrightarrow{f(\alpha,B')} f(A',B'),\\
   f(F,B)\xrightarrow{f(\alpha, B)}f(A',B)\xrightarrow{f(A',\beta)}f(A',B').
   $$

These two families and $f(\alpha,\beta)$ satisfy coherence conditions similar to that of *quasi-functor of two variables* introduced by Gray ("Adjointness for 2-Categories", page 56), but droping the first requirement on identities, which I shall not spell out here; see Gordon-Power-Street in "[Coherence for tricategory](http://books.google.de/books?id=m0eIjLi23uEC&lpg=PA7&ots=_JwsG8QYRq&dq=coherence%20of%20tricategory&pg=PA31#v=onepage&q&f=false)", where it is called cubical functors (so remove the line "which is an identity when either $\alpha$ or $\beta$ is an identity).

Notice that if $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{B}=*$, the trivial bicategory with one objects, one 1-cell, one 2-cell, then the above data should be equivalent to two monads in $\mathcal{C}$ on the same object satisfying a distributive law.

**Question**:

Does there exist a funny tensor product $\mathcal{A}\otimes \mathcal{B}$ such that the above data is the same as a single pseudofunctor $\mathcal{A}\otimes \mathcal{B}\to \mathcal{C}$? (Gray tensor product of bicategories?)

Answer (score 0):

Since this question was written, there is a paper [2-dimensional bifunctor theorems and distributive laws](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/37/34/37-34abs.html) by Faul–Manuell–Siqueira based on this idea. In particular, they prove a "bifunctor theorem" for lax functors between 2-categories (Theorem 3.2), and relate it to certain tensor products of 2-categories (see Theorem 4.10, the end of §4, and Theorem 5.3). Also relevant is the paper [Bifunctor Theorem and strictification tensor product for double categories with lax double functors](https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.13452) of Femić.